# File loop with wildcard

Tags: bash, file, loops, wildcard

I'm writing a small script, for starting scripts created in the background. This script is running in a loop and has to start the created file when it is found in the specified directory.

It works when only one file is in the directory, the created script removes itself when it's finisched. But when 2 or more scripts are created at the same time it failes to run the scripts.

I get a error : binary operator expected

```
#!/bin/bash   
files="/var/svn/upload/*.sh"
x=1
while :
do
echo Sleeping $x..
  if [ -f $files ]
  then
    for file in $files
    do
      echo "Processing $file file..."
      sh $file
      echo $(date +%d-%m-%y) $(date +%H:%M:%S) - Sleep $x - Script $f >>/var/log/upload.log
      x=0
      wait
    done
  fi
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 1
done
```

I created a work around wich is working without any problems:

```
#!/bin/bash
files="/var/upload/*.sh"
x=1
while :
do
  count=$(ls $files 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
  echo Sleeping $x..
  if [ "$count" != "0" ]
  then
    for file in $files
    do
      echo "Processing $file file..."
      sh $file
      echo $(date +%d-%m-%y) $(date +%H:%M:%S) - Sleep $x - Script $f >>/var/log/upload.log
      x=0
      wait
    done
  fi
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If the error refers to a specific line in your code, can you edit your post to specify which one?

Comment: The error is on line :  if [ -f $files ]

Answer (score 5):

One potential source of a similar problem is when the files matching the wildcard do not exist. In that case it just handles the word containint the `*` as such.

```sh
$ touch exist{1,2} alsoexist1
$ for file in exist* alsoexist* notexist* neitherexist*
> do echo $file
> done
exist1
exist2
alsoexist1
notexist*
neithereixt*
```

Answer (score 4):

The `-f` operator applies to only a single file, not the list that results by expanding  your unquoted `$files`. If you really need to capture the full list of files in a single variable, use an array, not a string. The `nullglob` option ensures that `files` is truly empty if the glob fails to match any files, eliminating the need for the `-f` test. There is also no need to call `wait`, as you aren't starting any background jobs.

```
#!/bin/bash  
shopt -s nullglob
x=1
while :
do
  echo Sleeping $x..
  for file in /var/svn/upload/*.sh
  do
    echo "Processing $file file..."
    sh "$file"
    echo $(date +%d-%m-%y) $(date +%H:%M:%S) - Sleep $x - Script "$f" >>/var/log/upload.log
    x=0
  done
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working.

But i had to move files=(/var/svn/upload/*.sh) to the line above echo Sleeping $x.. to work correctly..

Comment: Right; I missed the change in when the glob was actually applied. Given the change you suggest, we can do away with the array and just put the glob in the for loop itself.